Undo Snackbar with a SwipeToDismissBox
I'm starting to get into Jetpack Compose and am trying to implement a list where you can swipe to delete an item but you can also restore it via a Snackbar action. In the old XML-Layout-based world I managed to do this before but I cannot get it to work in Jetpack Compose.
I can add a swipe-to-delete behaviour that successfully deletes the item and I can also show the Snackbar afterwards. Inserting the item back into the list technically seems to work as well, but the problem seems to be that rememberSwipeToDismissBoxState() remembers that I swiped this item and keeps its state. So when the item is re-inserted, the if statement that checks the state to see if the item should be deleted just immediately triggers and deletes the item again.
The item itself is an entity saved in an SQLite database that I access via Room.
Does anybody know how or even if such functionalilty can be implemented using Compose?
I currently have the following code:
The list:
@Composable
fun WatchHistory(
    viewModel: WatchHistoryViewModel = viewModel(),
    navigator: Navigator = Navigator.current,
) {
    val entries = viewModel.entries.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }

    Scaffold(
        snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState)
        },
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.watch_history_title),
                        maxLines = 1,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        modifier = Modifier.basicMarquee()
                    )
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { navigator.back() }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.AutoMirrored.Default.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                },
                actions = { WatchHistoryMenu() },
            )
        },
        content = { contentPadding ->
            LazyColumn(contentPadding = contentPadding) {
                items(count = entries.itemCount, key = entries.itemKey { it.historyId }) { index ->
                    entries.get(index)?.let { item ->
                        WatchHistoryItem(
                            item = item,
                            onDelete = { id ->
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    viewModel.deleteEntry(id)

                                    val result =
                                        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Entry deleted", "Restore")

                                    if (result == SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed) {
                                        viewModel.undoDelete(item.toWatchHistoryEntry())
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets.safeDrawing
    )
}

The item:
@Composable
fun WatchHistoryItem(
    item: WatchHistoryVideoEntity,
    onDelete: (id: Int) -> Unit,
) {
    val swipeToDismissState = rememberSwipeToDismissBoxState()

    if (swipeToDismissState.currentValue == SwipeToDismissBoxValue.EndToStart) {
        onDelete(item.historyId)
    }

    SwipeToDismissBox(
        state = swipeToDismissState,
        backgroundContent = {}
    ) {
        VideoItem(item = item.video)
    }
}

The entities. The actual table contains WatchHistoryEntryEntity, the WatchHistoryVideoEntity gets created via a join with another table.
@Entity(tableName = "watchHistory", indices = [Index("watchDate")])
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class WatchHistoryEntryEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    override val id: Int = 0,

    @Json(name = "episodeId") val videoId: String,
    val watchDate: Instant = Instant.now()
) : BaseEntity<Int>

data class WatchHistoryVideoEntity(
    val historyId: Int,
    val watchDate: Instant,

    @Embedded val video: VideoEntity
) {
    fun toWatchHistoryEntry() = WatchHistoryEntryEntity(
        id = historyId,
        videoId = video.id,
        watchDate = watchDate,
    )
}


Can you post your WatchHistoryVideoEntity class?

As expected, it is not Stable and is causing recompositions. You should read about Compose Stability

Another suggestion would to not use your room db model class directly, instead map it to a UI class and extract only the parameters that you need to display in the UI for your UI State class

Can you elaborate on what parts aren't stable here? Or how that's affecting the behaviour? Obviously the list isn't stable because the items are changing. That's kind of the point though, since I want to be able to delete them. I'm assuming the list item is actually too stable here, because it appears to keep the swipeToDismissState from before the deletion.

Check this

I have, I just don't understand what exactly this has to do with my problem

I'm suspecting that the data class supplied to the Composable is not stable and due to that, it might be recreating the state and giving you the feeling that it is being reset

The state should be reset actually, that's what I want. The problem is that
swipeToDismissState.currentValue == SwipeToDismissBoxValue.EndToStart always evaluates to true after swiping, even after restoring it.

Try supplying the state from outside and see if it helps

Nope, already tried that before

Have you ever figured this out? I have the same problem-ish. I get the state to reset after I user 'state.snapTo(newState)' but after that it isn't swipable anymore.

@Oliver Unfortunately not :( I have stopped trying for now after nothing really worked
